# Converting cmd arguments to python

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.3, python-2.7

I am trying to set up a hyperlink in ArcMap that opens a specific file in a program we've developed.

Using the cmd *C:>"C:\Program Files\program.exe" file* in windows works fine, but how do I translate this into python script opening the cmd prompt and then running the command?

Answer (score 1):

Using either a python add-in or script tool you could use the `os.startfile()` or `subprocess.Popen()`methods to point to your file and open it or you may use the `subprocess.call([app, input_command])` to run a given command on an app.

*You may have to set it first in windows as the default app to open that particular file extension first (right click on file in Computer, select Open With> Choose default program option, and then browse for the .exe).*

Comment: Thanks, the trick was to separate the arguments as separate list elements, like this:
import subprocess
program = 'C:/Program Files/Program.exe'
subprocess.call([program, 'Barents SE', '2'])

Is it possible to run this as an ESRI hyperlink script from ArcMAP? Pasting the python script directly into the script window works, but there's an error message about OpenLink saying it is not defined..

Comment: What is OpenLink?

Comment: Got it now. OpenLink is the function you use to identify the variables you'll be using in the ESRI hyperlink script.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I've implemented successfully. I had two variables in the feature class table defining the file I wanted the program to open. Go to Layer Properties - Display and select Hyperlinks - Script. The ESRI hyperlink script looks like this:

```
import subprocess
program = 'C:/Program Files/your program.exe'    #program you want to use to open the files
def OpenLink ( [Region], [Transect_ID] ):        #defines the variables
  region = [Region]                              #set the first variable you will call
  transect = [Transect_ID]                       #set the second variable you will call
  subprocess.call([program, region, transect])    
  return
```

Replace subprocess.call with subprocess.Popen if you want to open the program as a separate task (recommended).